# Find largest subset where two elements share a property

Tags: algorithms

I have a set of numbers S and I want to find the largest subset S' such that for any two elements x,y in S' <del>`property(x, y) == True`</del> `in_relation(x,y) == True`.

How could I find it? Bruteforcing is an option, ok. But I'd like to find something more efficient.

Comment: Maybe I'm confused here, but isn't the answer to just take all elements for which the property is true? Or is your `property(x, y) == True` trying to imply that this "property" is actually a relation? (if it's a relation, then the answer is we have to brute-force it unless we know something about the relation that would let us skip testing some pairs)

Comment: Yes, it's a relation on S.

Comment: I think you're talking about the clique problem: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem Unfortunately, no efficient solution is known.

Comment: You are indeed *trying to solve the [Clique Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem)*, as [@Kilian foth](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/users/7422/kilian-foth) suggested.  In particular, you are searching for a [Maximal Clique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem#Maximal_versus_maximum) - *since you are looking for "the largest subset"*.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid thas this problem is NP-complete, and hence can (probably) only be solved by brute-forcing.

consider the IS (independent set) problem, which is NP-complete. We shall prove that this problem can be reduced to the problem described above.

Let G be a graph with Vertices set V. Let us build set S as numbers enumerating the vertices of V, and build property(x,y) as "x and y are not connected by an edge".

This build has the complexity of n^2 * complexity of property (if not polynomial than the problem is not polynomial by its nature. otherwise, the build is polynomial).

Now, let S' be the solution set found by the algorithm of the problem. since the set S and property are built exactly on V and the no-edge properties, S' can easily be transformed into the solution to the IS problem.

Therefore, our problem solves a NP-complete problem after a polynomial reduction and thus is NP-complete itself. to this day, it is not known about polynomial (non brute-force) solutions for NP-complete problems.

Comment: 1) Being NP-complete does not mean brute-forcing is the only option. It means we don't know any polynomial-time solutions, but many NP-complete problems have known solutions which are much better than brute force. A* pathfinding is a good example. 2) Your proof seems to be assuming that `property(x,y)` is an [equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation), which I don't think is a safe assumption until the OP tells us more about it.

Comment: oh, I didn't mean to actually say that brute-forcing is the only way, but rather saying that there is no efficient way, which is a polynomial solution. I see "brute-forcing" as an example to "messy and takes a lot of time" which is probably what the OP tries to avoid. as for the second note, would you like to provide an example of a property that won't fit?

Comment: 1) Since the OP asked for "more efficient" rather than "polynomial time", we shouldn't ignore the possibility of "more efficient than brute-force but still exponential time" solutions. That's all. 2) First, let's stop calling it a "property" if we're assuming OP really intended it to be a relation between two things instead of a property of one thing. But one trivial example of a non-equivalence relation would be "a path exists from x to y" in a directed graph, since that's not symmetric. Or "x is different from y" since that's not reflexive. Non-transitive is a bit harder but easy to Google.

Comment: I didn't ask for an example of a non-equivalence relation, but rather of an example to a... "function" that will break my proof.

Comment: Your proof is correct. My point was that the thing you're proving probably does not answer the OP's question (unless you got very lucky with your additional assumptions).